# If the curve with equation $y=x^3+px^2-4 $ is the tangent on long axis , Find the $p$

Tags: curves, tangent-line

question:

If the curve with equation $y=x^3+px^2-4 $  is  tangent with x -axis.

Find the $p$

I know:

tangent Means -> y=0 , y'(Slope of the line)=0

How can I get a complete and correct answer?

Thanks for your help

Comment: What does "is the tangent on long axis" mean, please?

Comment: $y=0$, $y'=0$ gives you two equations in the two unknowns $x$ and $p$. Try to solve them.

Comment: Apparently he means the $x$-axis, from conditions $y=0$ and $y'=0$ which indicate a tangent to the $x$-axis.

Comment: @GerryMyerson OK, thank you

Comment: Even if by "long axis" he means the x-axis: what does a function/curve being the tangent on long axis (or x-axis) mean? We can guess until tomorrow, yet I think it is due the OP to address and clear out this.

Comment: @hardmath Yes, My point is x -axis.

Comment: @Don, I'm guessing OP wants the value of $p$ that makes the graph tangent to the $x$-axis. If I'm wrong, I'll buy you a beer.

Comment: @DonAntonio I tried to edit my question.

Comment: I must $\color{green}{y=x^3 +px^2 −4}$ -> $\color{red}{y'=3x^2 +2px=0}$ Is this true?

Comment: @Software: I am so glad you can ask your question here. This is a good event +1

Comment: Rats! There goes my beer with @GerryMyerson ...

Answer (score 3):

Hints: You can obtain two equations in two unknowns by putting $y = 0$, and by finding $y'$, then setting $y' = 0$.

$$y=x^3+px^2-4 = 0 \iff \ldots$$

$$y' = 3x^2 + 2px = 0 \iff x(3x + 2p) = 0\iff \ldots$$

Comment: yes, It is true. So $x=0~,~x=\frac{-2p}{3}~\Rightarrow~p=3 $ Thank you dear friend :) $\huge\color{green}{✔}^\color{red}{❀}$ for you.

Comment: Thank you,Your guidance helped me.$\huge\color{blue}{☺}$

Comment: @amWhy: I hope she can do the rest. :+)

Comment: @amWhy: Nice feedback :-) +1

Comment: @amWhy can I ask a question? what is "amWhy" meaning??

Comment: @Software: <amWhy> Sound out, in English: the letter "a", the letter "m", and the *letter* that sounds like "Why". That spells my first name. :^)

Comment: @amWhy: Wow.
The name was a very nice selection.
This is really interesting.
I was always curious to know.
Thanks for the explanation. ;)